# Selecting Range

Tags: excel, vba

TL;DR:
*I would like it so that the range A6:A? down is pasted into range B10:B?*

I am trying to select a range of data to populate into another column. The range is coming from a table and is currently in range A6:A9, although this will extend.

The code that I am currently using is:

```
Sub Supplier_Names()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws_Temp As Worksheet
Dim Supplier_Names As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws_Temp = wb.Worksheets("Templates")

Set Supplier_Names = ws_Temp.Range("A6", Range("A6").End(xlDown))

ws_Temp.Range("B10") = Supplier_Names


End Sub
```

This works when I only select from range A6, but when I run it with the xlDown it does not enter any values into B10. It also does not come up with a debug box.

Any solutions would be great!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("A1").End(xlDown)` returns the [default property which is `Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)).

So for example, your current range is `A6:A9`, if `A9` has the word `Test` in it, your line becomes:
**`Set Supplier_Names = ws_Temp.Range("A6", "Test")`**. *though it should be noted Excel/VBA seems smart enough to work out what you are wanting to do and does infact use the cell address reference)*

You can use the [`Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address) property of `Range` to return the cell address that is found.

Like so:

`Set Supplier_Names = ws_Temp.Range("A6", Range("A6").End(xlDown).Address)`

Which would translate to:

`Set Supplier_Names = ws_Temp.Range("A6", "$A$9")`

I agree with @Dy.Lee answer that using an Array is a better way to do what you are wanting to do.

Like so:

```
Sub Supplier_Names()

Dim ws_Temp As Worksheet
Dim Supplier_Names_Array() As Variant

Set ws_Temp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Templates")

With ws_Temp
    Supplier_Names_Array = .Range("A6", .Range("A6").End(xlDown).Address)
    .Range("B10").Resize(UBound(Supplier_Names_Array, 1)) = Supplier_Names_Array
End With
End Sub
```

http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx is a great resource for learning about this method of using Arrays with the Worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

Using array is easy.

```
Sub Supplier_Names()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws_Temp As Worksheet
    Dim Supplier_Names As Range
    Dim vDB As Variant
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws_Temp = wb.Worksheets("Templates")
    With ws_Temp
        Set Supplier_Names = ws_Temp.Range("A6", .Range("A6").End(xlDown))
        vDB = Supplier_Names '<~~ use array
        .Range("b10").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1)) = vDB
    End With

End Sub
```

The following are the same. It doesn't matter which one is a character and which one is a range.

```
Dim rngDB As Range

Set rngDB = Range(Range("a1"), Range("a10"))

Set rngDB = Range("a1", "a10")

Set rngDB = Range("a1", Range("a10"))

Set rngDB = Range("a1:a" & 10)
```

Comment: You have used `With ws_Temp` so you don't need `ws_Temp` before `.Range("A6", .Range("A6").End(xlDown))` which makes me wonder how this works, but it does i.e. you have supplied mixed, the string `"A6"` and a cell range `Range("A6").End(xlDown)` as the parameters of a range object. Could you elaborate, please.

Answer (score 1):

I've introduced another range object to make it more readable:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Supplier_Names()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Temp As Worksheet
    Dim Supp As Range
    Dim Cust As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set Temp = wb.Worksheets("Templates")
    
    Set Supp = Temp.Range("A6")
    Set Supp = Temp.Range(Supp, Supp.End(xlDown))
    
    Set Cust = Temp.Range("B10")
    Set Cust = Cust.Resize(Supp.Rows.Count, Supp.Columns.Count)
    
    Cust.Value = Supp.Value

End Sub
```